# How to read a dataframe row by row and write to another dataframe row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to read two dataframes:

First dataframe is like:

```html
A B C
1 2 3
```

The second dataframe is like:

```html
D E F
8 9 12
2 4 6 
3 5 8
2 5 7
```

Now i want the third dataframe which would:

1. Have the length same as the second dataframe
2. Have the D E F columns with the values as
3. Values of A B C columns copied and repeated through the length of the file

So essentially the third dataframe should look like:

```html
A B C D E F 
1 2 3 8 9 12
1 2 3 2 4 6 
1 2 3 3 5 8
1 2 3 2 5 7
```

the code i have tried so far is:

```py
dataframe1
dataframe2


dataframe3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
for i in range(len(dataframe2)):
     dataframe3['A'] = dataframe1['A']
     dataframe3['B'] = dataframe1['B']
     dataframe3['C'] = dataframe1['C']
     dataframe3[i, 'D'] = dataframe2[i, 'D']
     dataframe3[i, 'E'] = dataframe2[i, 'E']
     dataframe3[i, 'F'] = dataframe2[i, 'F']
```

But this is not creating the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

use `pd.concat()`+`ffill()`:

```
out=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).ffill(downcast='infer')
#pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).fillna(downcast='infer',method='ffill')
```

output of `out`:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   2   3   8   9   12
1   1   2   3   2   4   6
2   1   2   3   3   5   8
3   1   2   3   2   5   7
```